# Display urdf file in gazebo

Tags: ros, gazebo, urdf, spawn-model

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I made a program that autommatically generate an .urdf file from a .fig file (generate by Xfig editor). When I display my urdf file with RViz, the objects and colors are like they should be so everything is normal. I use the command line :

```
roslaunch urdf_tutorial display.launch model:=PlanSalle.urdf
```

but when I want to display it in gazebo, it doesn't work. I use :

```
rosrun gazebo spawn_model -file `pwd`/PlanSalle.urdf -urdf -z 1 -model salle
```

here is my code :

```
<robot name="origins">
<link name="base_link">
    <visual>
        <geometry>
            <box size ="18.8 0.4 2"/>
        </geometry>
    </visual>
    <collision>
        <geometry>
            <box size ="18.8 0.4 2"/>
        </geometry>
    </collision>
        <inertial>
                <inertia ixx="0.0" ixy="0.0" ixz="0.0" iyy="0.0" iyz="0.0" izz="0.0"/>
        <mass value="0.1"/>
        </inertial>
</link>

<link name="Mur1">
    <visual>
        <geometry>
            <box size ="11.0 0.4 2"/>
        </geometry>
    </visual>
    <collision>
        <geometry>
            <box size ="11.0 0.4 2"/>
        </geometry>
    </collision>
        <inertial>
                <origin xyz="1 1 1" />
                <inertia ixx="0.0" ixy="0.0" ixz="0.0" iyy="0.0" iyz="0.0" izz="0.0"/>
        <mass value="10"/>
        </inertial>
</link>

<joint name="base_link_to_Mur1" type="fixed">
    <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0" />      
    <parent link="base_link"/>
    <child link="Mur1"/>
</joint> 
</robot>
```

Does someone know what's wrong ? thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/37310/display-urdf-file-in-gazebo/) by [Selim](https://answers.ros.org/users/2717/selim/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2012-06-26

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-06-26**:
What error are you getting?

**Comment by [Erwan R.](https://answers.ros.org/users/2176/erwan-r./) on 2012-06-26**:
In Gazebo, the object looks to be spawned (as it appears in the list) but can't be seen, as nothing is displayed. If the item is selected in the list, handles are appears to move it, suggesting that it is a displaying issue. In RViz, we are able to visualize the 3D model with the rights colors on...

**Comment by [Erwan R.](https://answers.ros.org/users/2176/erwan-r./) on 2012-06-26**:
... the walls. Maybe we are missing something about the way Gazebo and RViz use urdf files. Any help is appreciated.

**Comment by [mcevoyandy](https://answers.ros.org/users/2166/mcevoyandy/) on 2012-07-26**:
I just tried your file and it spawns fine for me.  have you tried updating to the latest version of gazebo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Thanks for answering.

We checked for the exact way urdf files must be written and we updated the python program that auto-generates the urdf (there were fields missing in the previous program). Now it's spawning well and walls are detected from sensors.

We're working with electric version.

---

Originally posted by [Erwan R.](https://answers.ros.org/users/2176/erwan-r./) with karma: 697 on 2012-07-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0